# How to get the result of strlen into an int without a warning when compiling with /Wp64

Tags: c++

int l = strlen(s);

warning C4244: '=' : conversion from '__w64 int' to 'int', possible loss of data

I need to replace strlen with an inline function
int l = new_strlen(s);

But how do I portably get the result of the strlen into the int without a warning, and without using pragmas?  I can guarantee there aren't more than 2 billion characters in my string!

All the obvious things like reinterpret_cast, static_cast  also produce errors or warnings.

EDIT: Argh. a c-style cast: (int) does work. I had been convinced that it did not.

Answer (score 5):

```
const char * str = "Hello";
int len = static_cast< int >( strlen( str ) );
return len;
```

This code doesn't produce any error or warning even on Warning Level 4 (VS2005).
What compiler do you use?

Answer (score 3):

Also note that /Wp64 is deprecated in VS2008; apparently it's [not reliable](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/08/10/the-future-of-the-c-language.aspx#4421146).

Comment: /Wp64 is probably a waste of time for 32-bit builds, but it's really helpful for 64-bit builds because it enables warnings you would not get otherwise.

Comment: If you're building for x64, you'll get the warnings anyway. /Wp64 is for when you're building for 32-bit, but want to be warned about potential 64-bit problems. But, regardless, it's broken: http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/08/10/the-future-of-the-c-language.aspx#4421146

Comment: I understand that /Wp64 was designed to give 64-bit compatibility warnings in 32-bit builds. However, if I open Visual C++ x64 cross tools command prompt and run cl.exe with and without /Wp64, I only get warnings about bad pointer<=>integer casts when I specify /Wp64 or /Wall, not /W4.

Answer (score 1):

Cast it:

```
int i = (int) strlen(s);
```

Comment: In this case, nothing.  This will simply construct a temporary int and initialize it with the value returned from strlen().  In other cases C-style casts can be dangerous, where there are safer alternatives such as static_cast or dynamic_cast.

Answer (score 1):

Or don't use a signed int.  The return value of strlen() is unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

In cases where you really have a good reason to truncate pointers, you can make `/Wp64` accept your code by stacking multiple casts. These cases are rare. One example: device drivers for legacy PCI devices, doing DMA, with memory allocated below the 4GB limit. (Note: there is also the `PtrToUlong()` macro, which will make your intentions clearer.)

This single cast will produce a warning:

```
const char* p = "abc";
unsigned int u = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int>(p);
```

wp64.cpp(10) : warning C4311: 'reinterpret_cast' : pointer truncation from 'const char *' to 'unsigned int'

But these stacked casts will not:

```
const char* p = "abc";
unsigned int u = static_cast<unsigned int>(reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(p));
```

I'm not able to reproduce your warning with the version of the compiler that I have installed, but I suspect that your problem is related to the fact that you're casting a 64-bit unsigned `size_t` into a 32-bit signed `int`.

You might have better luck if you stack multiple casts to do the 64-bit to 32-bit conversion and the unsigned-to-signed conversion:

```
const char* s = "abcdef";
int l = static_cast<int>(static_cast<intptr_t>(strlen(s)));
```

Also, if you build both x86 and x64 binaries, you can disable `/Wp64` for your 32-bit builds so that you don't have to annotate any types with `__w64`. Using `/Wp64` for your 64-bit builds will catch a lot of bugs.

Answer (score 1):

if you understand a warning, its perfectly acceptable to disable the warning instead of stacking casts or whatever other confusing mess as a workaround.

> A pragma warning directive with the
>   suppress specifier suppresses the
>   warning only for the line of code that
>   immediately follows the #pragma
>   warning statement.
>
> ```
> #pragma warning( suppress : 6001 ) 
> arr[i+1] = 0; // Warning 6001 is suppressed
> j++; // Warning 6001 is reported
> ```
>
> [(msvc specific)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468780.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

> I need to replace strlen with an
>   inline function int l = new_strlen(s);

Note that in VC++, strlen is automatically replaced by a inline version when you build an optimized version.